# Ng-repeat passando um numero

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Quero montar um select cujos os options serão gerados por um ng-repeat, mas para isto quero passar um numero, por exemplo se eu passar o numero 5 na variável vão ser montados 5 options com valores 1,2,3,4,5.

```
<md-select ng-disabled="!novoCadastro.curso" required ng-model="novoCadastro.periodo">
 <md-option ng-value=""></md-option>
 <md-option ng-value="periodo" ng-repeat="periodo in novoCadastro.curso.periodo">{{periodo}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

No meu novoCadastro.curso.periodo vai ser onde eu irei declara um numero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é uma boa prática o `value` ser gerado dinamicamente. Aconselho criar uma lista de dicionários ou de tuplas e indicar o `value` e o `text`.

```
// dicionario
novoCadastro.curso.periodo = [{1: 'Primeiro'}, {2: 'Segundo'}, ...];
// ou tupla
novoCadastro.curso.periodo = [(1, 'Primeiro'), (2, 'Segundo'), ...];
```

Se ainda sim quiser gerar o value pelo contador do loop, você pode usar `$index`;

```
<md-option ng-value="$index+1" ng-repeat="periodo in novoCadastro.curso.periodo">{{periodo}}</md-option>
```

O `$index` começa a contar em 0.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, já que não é uma boa pratica vou fazer conforme me falou.

Comment: @ErickZanetti não esquece depois de marcar como resposta aceita se resolver o seu problema. Valeu.